# Django boolean field views+templates

Tags: django, django-views

Here is my current setup:

http://dpaste.com/699684/

What I am looking to do is two things:

1. I want to include a new template if the boolean field value is true, for example

   ```
   {% if clearance=true %} {% include example.html %} {% endif %}
   ```

   I think that is easy(ish) but I cant work out how to get the value into a view then out into my template
2. I want to be able to define a new view called clearance that lists under "/clearance" that lists all products with the clearance boolean filed. I have one base polymorphic model and sevral other models that extend from there, Accessory is just one I have given as an example

   This I think maybe slightly harder due to polymorphic, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty much there on including a template for clearance items, you're just not using the right syntax:

```
{% if object.clearance %}{% include 'example.html' %}{% endif %}
```

Where `product` is the current product within the forloop or whatever.

For the clearance view all you need is:

```
class ProductClearanceView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products/clearance.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ProductClearanceView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(clearance=True)
```

Comment: Thanks I literally just had the 1st part and was posting my own answer and saw this, testing the other view now

Comment: url(r'^clearance/', ProductClearanceView.as_view()),   ?

Also how would I render the items in a list within my template?

Comment: Ideally I want the view like my others http://dpaste.com/699703/ @chris but idk if i can do one for ALL product based models (as its polymorphic)